# How can I make my Tumblr tags italicised?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-tags

I'm using [this theme.](http://www.snazzyspace.com/tumblr-theme/code/8b145f_pink-galaxy) I put the code below in to make tags visible, but I'm not sure how to make my tags italic/bold/underlined. Can anyone help me out? Google didn't help.

```
{block:HasTags}
       {block:Tags}
          <font size="2"> 
          <font color="#FFFFFF">
          <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
          </font>
          </font>
       {/block:Tags}
    {/block:HasTags}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `font` element is outdated. CSS should be used instead.

You can use this markup:

```
{block:HasTags}
  {block:Tags}
    <a href="{TagURL}" class="custom_tag">{Tag}</a>
  {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
```

And add this line to your CSS:

```
.custom_tag {color:#FFF; font-size:1.2em; font-style:italic;}
```

(You might have to adapt the `font-size` value; I don’t know what the `font` element’s `size="2"` corresponds to.)